# Need help w/ SSH port-forwarding on Airport Extreme

Tags: network, ssh, airport

Here is my setup -

---

DHCP Reservations -

Mapped Raspberry Pi (pi01) to internal IP address

---

Port Settings -

Remote Login - SSH

Public UDP Ports: 2200

Public TCP Ports: 2200

Private IP Address: [internal IP address from above]

Private UDP Ports: 22

Private TCP Ports: 22

---

Yet, I cannot connect to the RPi using `ssh https://[external IP address]:2200`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

SSH and HTTPS are different things. You can connect using

```
ssh -p 2200 [external IP address]
```

as a synopsis of in manual page for `ssh` explains:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> ssh [...] [-p port] [...] [user@]hostname [command]
> ```